# CLI SAPI based daemon, PHP app with cronjobs support

Tags: php, command-line-interface, cron, php53

I need to build an CLI SAPI based daemon, PHP app with cronjobs support for iOS platform. We have dedicated server.

What kind of  PHP environment to run this type of PHP applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check PHP CLI SAPI module whether installed

```
<?php
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
{
   // ...
}
?>
```

If not installed, then install it 
Debian Based Server

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Redhat/CentOS Based Servers

```
yum install php5-cli
```

**and make sure you are running your script in CLI mode**